# Creating Woocommerce Product Attribute From CSV File

Tags: woocommerce

I have attributes in the form of a CSV file. What I want to do is just create these attributes. I do not need to define any product. How can I do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Import one product with [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-import-export-for-woo/) along with all the attributes. It's done. Sample CSV link is there in the page

Comment: @mujuonly thank you. it works. I would like to do this without actually needing the plugin. I hope there is an answer for this too. Thanks again.

Comment: Understood. Then the solution with this plugin will be enough. :) Thanks again. @mujuonly